# Can someone explain me the answer of this code in java?

Tags: java, string

This is the problem

> Given a string, return a version where all the "x" have been removed.
>   Except an "x" at the very start or end should not be removed.
>
> - `stringX("xxHxix")` → `"xHix"`
> - `stringX("abxxxcd")` → `"abcd"`
> - `stringX("xabxxxcdx")` → `"xabcdx"`

Now I understand the problem but the solution is unclear for me, can someone explain me?

answer=

```
public String stringX(String str) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    // Only append the char if it is not the "x" case
    if (!(i > 0 && i < (str.length()-1) && str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x"))) {
      result = result + str.substring(i, i+1); // Could use str.charAt(i) here
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

My solution that is also valid is this one =

```
public String stringX(String str) {

  String ans = "";

  if(str.length() == 0) return ans;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'x') ans += "x";

  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
  {
    if(str.charAt(i) == 'x') continue;
    ans += (char) str.charAt(i);
  }

  if(str.charAt(str.length()-1) == 'x' && str.length() > 1) ans += "x";

  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Explain what part of it?

Comment: Why this question was downvoted?

Comment: The entire method can be achieved in one line: `return str.replaceAll("(?<!^)x(?!$)", "")`

Comment: Whoever wrote that solution really needs to learn how many String objects (s)he just created by calling all those `substring`s and `+=`

Comment: @SamSun I have a feeling it was written that way to help visualize each step (like as if it were from a tutorial)

Comment: I personally like your answer better. More clarity even though it's less concise. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String stringX(String str) {

  // Create an empty string to hold the input without 'x's
  String result = "";

  // Loop for as many characters there are in the string
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {

    // If the current character we're looking at isn't the first OR last character
    // and we check to see if that character equals 'x', then we take the opposite
    // of this entire value.
    // Another way to read this logic is:
    // If the character we're looking at is the first OR the last OR it doesn't equal 'x',
    // then continue (return true)
    if (!(i > 0 && i < (str.length()-1) && str.substring(i, i+1).equals("x"))) {

      // We add this character to our output string
      result = result + str.substring(i, i+1); // Could use str.charAt(i) here
    }
  }

  // Return our output string
  return result;
}
```